# Custom validation using web service in silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

I am trying to validate a textbox input (in Silverlight) using validation annotations with custom validator which is supposed to validate input on a server side. My problem is that web service call is asynchronous, so I can't return a validation result since validation method is sync on the client side.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into INotifyDataErrorInfo. This allows asynchronous validation.

Here are some links that may be helpful:
http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-binding-with-inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/22/silverlight-4-and-asynchronous-validation-with-inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Whether the web service is implemented asynchronously should not have any effect on the client as far as I know. For the client it will call the web service and wait for a response. If the response does not come on time, there will be a time out. It should not matter whether the web service executes asynchronously.